# How to to center anchor and img to be responsive

Tags: css, image, anchor, centering

```
 <div class="testt">
        <div class="test">
            <img src="4.jpg">
            <a href="">test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <img src="5.jpg">
            <a href="">test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <img src="7.jpg">
            <a href="">test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <img src="6.jpg">
            <a href="">test</a>
        </div>
```

If you can help me for the pictures to be one line and the anchor beneath them nicely centered and also to be responsive for all devices

Comment: first:where is your try ? , second for responsive image use percentage to height and width , and to center thing you must specify the main div width then use margin:0 auto to make children in center of main div.

Comment: please attach your style sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` on the parent and that will put everything on one line, give it a relative `width` so that it scales with the viewport, assign `text-align: center;` to the `.test` divs to center the contents, and give the `img` a `max-width: 100%` so that it scales with the parent size.

```css
.testt {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
.test {
  text-align: center;
}
.test img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="testt">
  <div class="test">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    <a href="">test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    <a href="">test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    <a href="">test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Igor awesome you're welcome. Welcome to SO btw. Be sure to upvote answers if you think they have helped, and once you feel your problem has been resolved, be sure to accept an answer (the checkmark by answers) so that others don't think it's still open and continue to provide answers.

Comment: Now i have another problem...I want to make a little space between the anchor and the image I tried margin-top but doesn't working.

Comment: @Igor it's bad etiquette to introduce new problems and seek help in the comments. If you have a new issue and you can't resolve it on your own, you should make a new post. That said, just add `margin-bottom: 1em;` to `.test img`. And like I recommended, be sure to accept an answer **once the question in your post has been resolved**, and it seems like it has.

Comment: Ok, I didnt know about that,but thx anyway i solve my problem.

Comment: @Igor no problem :)